# Virus Total, Windows Defender define my application as a trojan, how to fix it?

Tags: c#, winforms

For a long time, I still can't solve my issue that defender still define my application as a trojan.
Im new at winform framework (C#). I made an application that will rename and extract zip file, but for some ridiculous reason, my app got delete at every computer cause they define my app as an trojan except i turn off windows defender. Someone tell me that my code not unsafe and someone tell me something about GUID, signing.

Please, i realy need some help. These are my main code and some pic about my issue, also, sorry for my bad english:

```
//my library
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Dialogs;
using System.IO.Compression;

//main code
private void btBrowseM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            CommonOpenFileDialog browse = new CommonOpenFileDialog();
            browse.IsFolderPicker = true;
            if (browse.ShowDialog() == CommonFileDialogResult.Ok)
            {
                selectedPath = browse.FileName;
                lbfolderPath.Text = selectedPath;
            }
        }

        private void btClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }

        private void btInstallM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            string sourceFilePath = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "Resource.bin");
            if (selectedPath == null)
            {
                pWrongpath.Visible = true;
                timer1.Start();
            }
            else
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(sourceFilePath))
                {

                    try
                    {
                        using (ZipArchive archive = ZipFile.OpenRead(sourceFilePath))
                        {
                            foreach (ZipArchiveEntry entry in archive.Entries)
                            {
                                string fullPath = Path.Combine(selectedPath, entry.FullName);

                                // Create directory if needed
                                if (entry.FullName.EndsWith("/") || entry.FullName.EndsWith("\\"))
                                {
                                    Directory.CreateDirectory(fullPath);
                                    continue;
                                }

                                // Extract the file
                                entry.ExtractToFile(fullPath, true);
                            }
                        }

                        pSucceded.Visible = true;
                        timer1.Start();

                    }
                    catch (System.Exception ex)
                    {

                        pFail.Visible = true;
                        timer1.Start();
                    }


                }

            }
        }
```

Thanks for spent your free time and read this post. Im still trying to figure out the solution.

Comment: Hi if your running your application from the Rider development environment then there is an option to exclude your project's files from windows defender

Comment: Try and generate a setup for your program, install it and then  try to run and see if windows defender still blacklists them.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are not using any kind of cracked component on your VS ?

If so , reinstall your C#.NET and do not use those  component .

I had this kind of problem and after reinstalling VS and not using those my problem solved .

Comment: i don't know, Im using VS community, and install pack on this. I also install some nuget pack in my project, there are MicroSoft.APIcodepack which allow me using common browse folder dialog and "costura fody" which allow me combine all of .dll file.
Some reason, i solved 2 problem, these problem from my nuget pack, that is "costura fody" , they changed hex in my project , after removed it, everything fine, the last issue that i have is Malware.AI.4131347519 in my project.